# pandas concat adding as columns with nans?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, each with the same number of columns :

```py
print(df1.shape)
(54, 35238)

print(df2.shape)
(64, 35238)
```

And both don't have any index set

```py
print(df1.index.name)
None

print(df2.index.name)
None
```

However, whenever I try to vertically concat them (so to have a third dataframe with shape (118, 35238)), it produces a new df with NaNs:

```py
df3 = pandas.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
print(df3)
```

[image: df3 print result]

The resultant df has the correct number of rows, but it has decided to concat them as new columns. Using the "axis" flag set to 1 results in the same number of (inappropriate) columns (e.g. shape of (63, 70476)).

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Try it without `ignore_index`. I believe that cause all of the columns to become mere numbers. The index it is ignoring here are columns (`df.columns` is of type Index). So ignoring them just creates a dataframe with columns 0 to N. If you do not ignore the columns, pandas will try to put them at the right place

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy forgot to mention that changing the `ignore_index` flag also doesn't appear to change the behavior/result at all

Comment: Really. So whether it is `True` or `False` doesn't change anything

Comment: Pass in the `axis` parameter based on whether you want rows or columns

Comment: are the columns named the same?

Comment: `ignore_index` is **only** important in labeling the output. The original indices are still respected during the join.

Comment: @Ben.T yes columns have same name (numbered 0 - 35238)

Comment: Try: `pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1,ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have the same number of columns, but are the column names different? The documentation on `concat` suggests to me that you need identical column names to have them stack the way you want.

If this is the problem, you could probably fix it by changing one dataframe's column names to match the other before concatenating:

```
df2.columns = df1.columns
```

Comment: They appeared to be identical... (all were int32 type and numbered 0=35238) but this was the solution, thankyou so much!

Comment: @DrTchocky just be careful. IMO, you should really figure out *why* the columns aren't identically named. While this will get it to work, it's highly prone to errors. This assumes the information in the columns are identically ordered in both frames, and given that the names aren't consistent, I'd personally be wary of the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because your df2 is a series, you can try:
`pd.concat([df1, pd.DataFrame([df2])], axis=0,  ignore_index=True)`